# how to get the current opened applications in windows using c++ or vb.net?

Tags: .net, c, windows

i need the current opened applications(those that appear in the task bar) and NOT the currently running processes.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enumerate all the top level windows (with the [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28VS.85%29.aspx) function); you have to skip:

- the invisible windows (check the return value of the [IsWindowVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633530%28VS.85%29.aspx) function or directly check if the window has the WS_VISIBLE style);
- the windows with the extended style WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, unless they have also the WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style.

All the others should be the ones shown in the taskbar ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776822%28VS.85%29.aspx)'s the full story).

Then, if you want to get the process/thread owning each of the window, you can use the [GetWindowThreadProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.